# Eigen values of a tensor product of the linear transformations

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, tensor-products

I want to investigate what kind of eigen values cat tensor product $A \otimes B$ of two linear transformations have, s.t $(A \otimes B)z = \lambda z$.

If $z$ is a simple tensor then $\lambda = \alpha \beta$, where $\alpha,\beta$ are eigen values of $A,B$ respectively - easy to prove.

How can I find eigen values if $z = \sum_{ij}\gamma_{ij}x_i \otimes y_j$ is not a simple tensor, where $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_j\}$ are the bases?

My proof is not "good looking":

1. Assume an eigen vector $z = x \otimes y$ is a simple tensor, then $\lambda z = (A \otimes B)(z)$ and:

$\lambda(x \otimes y) = \lambda z = (A \otimes B)(z) = (A \otimes B)(x \otimes y) = Ax \otimes By$. Since both $\lambda (x \otimes y)$ and $Ax \otimes By$ are simple tensors, $Ax = \alpha x$ and $By = \beta y$, for some scalars $\alpha, \beta$, where $\alpha \beta = \lambda$. Therefore $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are proper values of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

2. Assume an eigen vector $z$ is not a simple tensor and a linear combination $z = \sum_{pq}\gamma_{pq} x_p \otimes y_q$.

Equation of a proper value:

$\lambda z = (A \otimes B)(z) = (A \otimes B)(\sum_{ij}\gamma_{ij} x_i \otimes y_j) = \sum_{ij}\gamma_{ij} Ax_i \otimes By_j$.

Let $Ax_i = \sum_{p}\alpha_{pi}x_p$ and $By_j = \sum_{q}\beta_{qj}y_q$.

Then:

$\lambda z = \sum_{ij}\gamma_{ij} (\sum_{p}\alpha_{pi}x_p) \otimes (\sum_{q}\beta_{qj}y_q) = \sum_{pq} (\sum_{ij}\gamma_{ij}\alpha_{pi}\beta_{qj})x_p \otimes y_q$

For all $p$ and $q$ we have $\sum_{ij}\gamma_{ij}\alpha_{pi}\beta_{qj} = \lambda \gamma_{pq}$.

Small observation: $f_{pq}(z) = \sum_{ij}\gamma_{ij}\cdot (\alpha_{pi}\beta_{qj}/\lambda) = \gamma_{pq}$ looks like a dual basis.

What's next?

If $z$ can be any vector, then I solve this equation for all $z \in \{ x_p \otimes y_q : p = 1.. n, q = 1..m \}$ - basis of a tensor product, and get the following result: $A = \alpha \cdot 1$ and $B = \beta \cdot 1$ and $\alpha \beta = \lambda$.

Comment: Does your "$\alpha\beta$" construction give you the right number of eigenvalues?

Comment: All of the eigenvalues are given by products of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. This is a bit tricky to prove if $A$ or $B$ isn't diagonalizable, though.